# cursor reversed for insert and replace mode in Editor

Tags: intellij-idea

I encounter a problem with the newest verison of the intellij-idea.It is about the cursor in the editor.

The usually situation:

**insert mode**: insert cursor, look like:

[image]

**replace mode**: block or rectangle cursor ,like right of the below picture

[image]

**However, the my case is the tow cursor is reversed.**

**insert mode: block cursor**

**replace mode: insert cursor**

I have try to find the solution and any setting on IDEA for this issue, but I cannot find any same issue.

I also try to install the VIM plguin for IDEA, and after enable the plugin, the cursor is normal, but after disable the plguin, the cursor is reversed again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Editor | General | Appearance** there is a *Use block caret* option. Did you maybe accidentaly check that? Also, have you tried turning in off and on?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will help someone else at some point. I installed the IdeaVim with the latest installation of IntelliJ. When switching to xml files, the cursor would automatically change to a block and I was unable to edit anything. Uninstall the plugin in Mac by going to IntelliJ IDEA (top left hand corner of the window) -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Search for IdeaVim -> Uninstall

Answer (score 1):

Also, by default in Mac any editor comes with insert mode like in intellij-idea:

So we need to uninstall the VIM from intellij-idea in this case

Preferences ---> Plugins ----> VIM (uninstall) and restart the intellij-idea